# 'pymongo' Python Package Installation

Tags: python

I was interested to work with MongoDB. So, I tried to install 'pymongo' package with Terminal.

My used Command:

```
pip install pymongo
```

My Output:

```
Collecting pymongo
Downloading pymongo-3.11.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (530 kB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 530 kB 3.3 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-3.11.3
```

Then I opened Python and typed 'import pymongo'

My output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

[My work in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOrKd.png)

Anyone can help with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `python2`, and then here `import pymongo` .

Answer (score 0):

if you use IDE, you need to use System environment. if you use terminal, try to download with `sudo pip3 install pymongo`.